# Pandas how to apply normalization on a column with a condtion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a data frame like below and i want to normalize the values per customer .please help me how to achieve the solution.I tried minmaxscaler from sklearn on complete price column but it is giving me values close to zero.

Dataframe

```
Customer   price
  A          0
  A          3
  A          7
  A          0
  A          0
  B          2
  B          2
  B          0
  C          5
  C          1
  D          0
  D          0
  D          15 
  D          0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want *per customer*,

```
df.groupby('Customer').price.transform(\
              lambda s: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(s.values.reshape(-1,1)).ravel()
)
```

---

```
0     0.000000
1     0.428571
2     1.000000
3     0.000000
4     0.000000
5     1.000000
6     1.000000
7     0.000000
8     1.000000
9     0.000000
10    0.000000
11    0.000000
12    1.000000
13    0.000000
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ,i want slightly different output, where the normalized price should sum up to 1 per customer

Comment: if i want to run the normalization for multiple columns like for price , weight..etc, how can i do it , can u pls help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it without MinMaxScaler:

```
df["norm"]=df.groupby("Customer").apply(\
lambda grp: grp.price.div(grp.price.max()) ).values                         

       Customer  price      norm
    0         A      0  0.000000
    1         A      3  0.428571
    2         A      7  1.000000
    3         A      0  0.000000
    4         A      0  0.000000
    5         B      2  1.000000
    6         B      2  1.000000
    7         B      0  0.000000
    8         C      5  1.000000
    9         C      1  0.200000
    10        D      0  0.000000
    11        D      0  0.000000
    12        D     15  1.000000
    13        D      0  0.000000
```

**Edit:**
For another normalization, you can divide by grp.price.sum() instead of grp.price.max().

**Edit2:**
For more columns you can do:

```
    cols=["price","weights"]  # group the requested column names
    df2= df.groupby("Customer").apply(lambda grp: grp[cols].div(grp[cols].max()) )

    new_df=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
```

You must rename the last, normalized columns:

```
    new_df.columns                                                                                                       
    Index(['Customer', 'price', 'weight', 'price', 'weight'], dtype='object')
    new_df.columns= df.columns.append(pd.Index(["norm_"+c for c in df2.columns]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ,i want slightly different output, where the normalized price should sum up to 1 per customer

Comment: @mukesh tech01 See the note in the code segment above.

Comment: if i want to run the above normalization code for multiple columns like for price , weight..etc, how can i do it , can u pls help me on this

Comment: Thanks for the reply , can you please help with inverse transform to get the original price values for above code

Comment: What are you thinking exactly? You can only do that if you know the max price (in case of normalizing by max) or the sum of prices  (in case of normalizing by sum).